# VSTS, how to always get to artifact directory?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I can get to the artifact location by hard coding it:
`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_Testing-CI\test\`

But can I somehow get the source alias and artifact name from some variables in the release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to get the source alias name/Artifact name from the environment variable.

As of now, you need to specify the `Artifact alias name` in order to access the artifact related information.

E.g, `Release.Artifacts.{alias}.DefinitionName`

[General Artifact variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#artifact-variables)

[Primary Artifact Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#primary-artifact-variables)

As per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#using-default-variables)

> You can use the default variables in two ways - as parameters to tasks
>   in a release pipeline or in your scripts.
>
> You can directly use a default variable as an input to a task. For
>   example, to pass `Release.Artifacts.{Artifact alias}.DefinitionName` for
>   the artifact source whose alias is ASPNET4.CI to a task, you would use
>   `$(Release.Artifacts.ASPNET4.CI.DefinitionName)`.
>   [image]
>
> To use a default variable in your script, you must first replace the .
>   in the default variable names with _. For example, to print the value
>   of artifact variable `Release.Artifacts.{Artifact
>   alias}.DefinitionName` for the artifact source whose alias is
>   ASPNET4.CI in a Powershell script, you would use
>   `$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_ASPNET4_CI_DEFINITIONNAME`
>
> [image]
>
> Note that the original name of the artifact source alias,
>   `ASPNET4.CI`, is replaced by `ASPNET4_CI`

**You can upvote [this feedback](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33032560-introduce-vsts-release-variables-release-artifact) in order to achieve your request**

Answer (score 15):

It looks like it is now possible to use `$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)`. This would mean your artifact drop is at: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)/drop`